# Make white and gradient into transparent PNG file using Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I need to convert this image (left one) into another with transparent background preserving the shadow below, that is like a gradient, I know that PNG files have multiple levels of transparent, I have another image that acts as mask for the part of the image that must NO be transparent.

Note: Images seems different because I crop them out manually but the mask file is a perfect match for the image (same size and position).

Lighter portion of the left image must be fully transparent and darker portion of the shadow must be less transparent.

[image]
[image: mask]

Comment: What is your question? Did you try writing a program to do this, and need some help with it? If so, what exactly do you need help figuring out?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a strange request. Anyways, this code should do what you need. Does this help?

```
import cv2

input_image = cv2.imread('input.png',0)

# Dummy mask to try since I did not have the mask image.
#ret, dummy_mask = cv2.threshold(input_image, 0, 50, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
#mask = cv2.bitwise_not(dummy_mask)

# Your mask with 0s and 1s
mask = cv2.imread('mask.png',0)
# Retain the masked parts
non_alpha = cv2.bitwise_and(input_image, input_image, mask=mask)

# Get the alpha mask
alpha_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
alpha_source = cv2.bitwise_and(input_image, input_image, mask=mask)
alpha = cv2.bitwise_not(alpha_source)

#merge them
composite = cv2.merge((non_alpha, non_alpha, non_alpha, alpha));
cv2.imwrite("output.png", composite)
```